# Show all borders in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I am currently using the MigLayout. Does anybody have an idea how to show all the borders inside the MigLayout? I want it to look like a table or a grid.

Comment: Layout managers in Swing don't handle borders, borders are applied to the controls in the layout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder(javax.swing.border.Border)

Comment: Do `setBackground(Color.xxx)` on the component(s) to see the edges.

Comment: If you mean the gaps added by MigLayout, you can add a `debug x` constraint to the layout, where x is the number of milliseconds between each refresh.

Comment: Ok, it seems that there is no real solution. Only a few workarounds. But many thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a MigLayout question but the answer is:
`panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.gray));`

Comment: Just pointing out this doesn't answer the question. This will only outline the panel's border, but doesn't fulfill the requested behavior.

Comment: Jubbat, I was under the understanding that he wanted to show all borders in MigLayout and this does in fact accomplish that. Is there something more specific I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to complement Mitch Connor's answer with my findings.

This is how the create the MigLayout with global constraints and 4 columns :

```
  final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel( new MigLayout( "insets 0 0 0 0, gap 0 -1, wrap 4, fill",
      "0 [ right, fill ] -1 [ right, fill ] 10 [ right, fill ] -1 [ right, fill ] 0 " ) ) ;
```

This is the Border I set to the components inside :

```
  private static Border MARKET_DEPTH_CELL_BORDER = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
      BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Colors.GRAY_HALF, 1 ),
      BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder( 2, 10, 2, 10 )
  ) ;
```

Please note that MigLayout's insets are hacked to superimpose adjacent borders. To get space around the component itself I add an empty Border.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));`